# How can i send invite to another user using Exchange API

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

How can i send a outlook invite to another user using exchange API? Actually i'm trying this.

```
   ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
   service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("example@server.com", "example");
   Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);
```

But i need send invite to ANOTHER user, using his email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add(new Attendee("example@server.com"));` for send invite to the person.